# Singleton QNetworkAccessManager not directing the response to desired form

Tags: qt, singleton, qnetworkaccessmanager

In a small Qt application, I have a NetworkAccessManager(NAM) wrapped in a singleton class. NAM object of this class is used by four independent form classes. Each form class fires a request to a separate php (and php takes at least 3 seconds with sleep(3)).

Now there are two cases:

Case I: When NAM, for each form, is connected to form's slot IN CONSTRUCTOR.
    In this case, when i send requests from all four forms simultaneously; all the responses are directed to just one form (the one that was first in firing the request) and not to the form that requested it.

Case II: When NAM is connected (for firing request) and disconnected (when response is received) to form's slot IN FUNCTIONS (and not constructor).
    In this case, when i send requests from all four forms simultaneously (i.e. in less than 3 seconds); then only the first response is returned and the rest never returned. This is in accordance with the code as singleton NAM was disconnected as soon as it received the reply for the first request. Therefore other requests could not be processed.

All form classes are identical and use the same code. Here is the code (Case II specific):

```
void Request2::slotStartRequest(){
   m_Req2 = NetworkAccessManager::getInstance();
   connect(m_Req2, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(slotReplyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
   QString postData = "value=222";
   m_Req2->post(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(path)), postData.toUtf8());
}

void Request2::slotReplyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply){
   disconnect(m_Req2, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(slotReplyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
   ui->TEdit_Req2->setText(reply->readAll());
   reply->deleteLater();
}
```

Though the code for both cases are very similar. This code is Case II specific. For Case I, only change is that 'connect' and 'getInstance' codes are put in constructor (and there is no 'disconnect').

The code will work fine with one NetworkAccessManager object per form class.

But how do I achieve the desired behaviour (with one NAM for whole application) that response is directed only to the form that requested it and also the requests for other forms should not be affected ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NAM function `post()` creates a new `QNetworkReply` instance to manage that request. It is possible to connect directly to `QNetworkReply` signals instead of signals of `QNetworkAccessManager`:

```
void Request2::slotStartRequest(){
   QString postData = "value=222";
   QNetworkAccessManager *nam = NetworkAccessManager::getInstance();
   m_Reply = nam->post(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(path)), postData.toUtf8());    
   connect(m_Reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(slotReplyFinished()));
}
```

Now only this instance of `QNetworkReply *m_Reply` can call the signal of `this`. Note that there is no `QNetworkReply *reply` argument in the `finished()` signal:

```
void Request2::slotReplyFinished(){
   ui->TEdit_Req2->setText(m_Reply->readAll());
   m_Reply->deleteLater();
}
```

Comment: Well, you again helped me out. Happy with your support :-)

Comment: Well, if I have to make two simultaneous requests from a single form with Singleton NAM; then do I need two QNetworkReply object ? Or is there any other simpler way ?

Comment: @Jatin For two requests you will have two `QNetworkReply` objects. It depends on your project design how those replies are handled. You can have two different instances of `Request2` and each such instance can work with its own reply. It is possible to work with one `Request2` and multiple replies.

Comment: Ok. Means **either** it has to be multiple instances of 'Request2' each handling its own reply **or** single instance handling multiple reply objects. Am I right in interpreting your reply ?

Comment: @Jatin Yes, it is correct. However, the solution should be relevant to real application usage. For example, it is strange that two different web replies should set text into one UI control `TEdit_Req2`. Maybe new request should not be allowed before previous is finished or the second request should be put in queue or active `m_Reply` should be aborted (deleted) and new request should be straged...

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion (what I do) is to keep track of which object made the request on the manager, perhaps update your manager to take in the object pointer

```
m_Req2->post(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(path)), postData.toUtf8(), this);
```

Then on the Manager, use that pointer and use the QMetaObject to invoke the method, instead of emitting a signal: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod.

So you get something like this, on the Manager

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(obj, "slotReplyFinished", Qt::DirectConnection,
                      Q_ARG(QNetworkReply*, reply));
```

(not tested, but you should get the idea)

[edit: fixed code]

Comment: For this case perhaps Qt::Directconnection is not what you need, perhaps Queued, but if you need direct connection perhaps considering an interface and calling the method directly on the passed object `obj->slotReplyFinished(reply)`

Comment: I worked on your good suggestion of keeping track of object. In Manager, I used [qRegisterMetaType<QNetworkReply *>("QNetworkReply *");
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(obj, "slotReplyFinished", Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(QNetworkReply*, reply));] since slotReplyFinished takes QNetworkReply* (and not QNetworkReply as you told). But reply->readAll() is empty now. Am I using it correctly? And why is the reply content empty?

Comment: And one more point. Since I am new to using invokeMethod(), i used [connect(this, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), obj, SLOT(slotReplyFinished(QNetworkReply*)), Qt::QueuedConnection);] from the Manager hoping it to produce same effect as you suggested (keeping track of object and calling its slot()). But it resulted in Case I of question, all responses were directed to one form. Is this approach not the same as you suggested?

Comment: On comment 1: Use the pointer through the invoke: `Q_ARG(QNetworkReply*, reply))`, see if that makes a difference. Did your slot get called on the correct object at least?

Comment: Comment 2: No, but you can get it to work, but you need to `connect` then `emit` the signal and then `disconnect`. Otherwise the old connections will stay valid, then next time the slot gets called, the slot on the new and old object will be called. Then you must also make sure that the slot that does the emit (on the NAM) can not execute in parallel (normally it should not) but if it does you can have the same issue

Comment: Sorry. It is [Q_ARG(QNetworkReply*, reply))] already. I noticed it now. And yes, the slot gets called but with empty reply content.

Comment: Problem is resolved with Orest's answer. And it is good you introduced me to new invokeMethod. :-)