# QNetworkAccessManager to download image previews from the Internet crashes

Tags: qt, qt5, qnetworkaccessmanager

I have QListWidget each custom widget in it contains a label that gets it's QPixmap from the Internet using QNetworkAccessManager defined in each custom widget.

Everything works fine when there are 10, 20, 30 widgets added to QListWidget.

When amount of widgets (each of them has QNetworkAccessManager to load an image from the Internet) reached 300/400 the application became broken. Thread errors arrive.

How to avoid threading errors when there are a lot (300-2000)  QNetworkAccessManagers in application which load images from the Internet the same time?

I'm using Qt 5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally only one `QNetworkAccessManagers` is needed per application. It is quite heavy object that is able simultanenously manage many parallel connections. It also manages sockets and sessions, so all HTTP requests to the same server can be maintained by single (or few; it is configurable) TCP connection (once a request is finished the TCP connection is not closed and the next request is started in the same connection).

The usual reason for creation many instances of `QNetworkAccessManagers` is the trouble of hanling its asynchronous signals from separate connections.
Note that it is possible to connect signals not from but from `QNetworkReply` to approriate slot.

The functions `QNetworkAccessManager::get()` and `QNetworkAccessManager::post()` return pointer to `QNetworkReply` object that is responsible for that request. The signals of that `QNetworkReply` object can be connected to the slots of appropriate widget. So, once that reply is finished it will trigger only one specific widget slot, see for example [Singleton QNetworkAccessManager not directing the response to desired form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33537874/singleton-qnetworkaccessmanager-not-directing-the-response-to-desired-form/33544628#33544628)

Comment: I've also tried to have only one QNetworkAccessManager's  and have a slot assigned to `this` where this was finished() signal `connect(mainWindow->thumbsNetworkAccessManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(slot_netwManagerFinished(QNetworkReply*)));` *but* in this case what I get is the first widget has it's image updated many times, instead of every of those 300-400 widgets has updated each of their image

Comment: @Zelid It is better to connect not `QNetworkAccessManagers` but directly `QNetworkReply` with required widget. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! That worked fine. finished() signal from QNetworkReply is connected to slot that will handle the received data and sender is dynamically casted to QNetworkReply - then everything happens like it should